# Thread inside a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

This `thread` will use a`class` to process a certain transaction. But the requirement is, this `class` need to be a thread to avoid slowdown when the two threads concurrently accessing this `class`. How can I make a `thread` of that?

Comment: What is "mini thread"?

Comment: If you have two threads accessing same instance of object then you need some kind of locking mechanism to avoid data corruption and race condition.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan how can i achieve that locking mechanism? can you give me an example..

Comment: See 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: It is syntactic sugar for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Shared resource between multi thread application can be synchronized using locks or Monitor.Enter logic. Below are few reference links for basic multithread understanding

- http://www.bogotobogo.com/CSharp/csharp_multithreading3.php
- https://blog.goyello.com/2014/01/21/threading-in-c-7-things-you-should-always-remember-about/

Answer (score 0):

There's no *inherent* slowdown when an object is accessed by multiple threads at the same time, but you might run into race condition problems if data reads and writes are intermixed. A typical solution would be to use the [lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to [synchronize access to the object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679037.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Keep in mind that multithreaded programming can be very difficult to get right.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example of how to access resource from multiple thread safely.

### Thread Unsafe Version

```
class Program
{
    private static decimal _balance = 100;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Withdraw, 23m);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Withdraw(object state)
    {
        var value = (decimal)state;
        var prevBalance = _balance;

        if (_balance >= value)
        {
             Thread.Sleep(50); // simulate longer operation to emphasize data corruption
            _balance = _balance - value;
            Console.WriteLine("Balance {0}. Withdraw {1}. Balance after withdraw {2}", prevBalance, value, _balance);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Balance {0}. Withdraw failed", prevBalance);        
    }
}
```

This code will result in unexpected (and unpredicted) result because variable `_balance` is accessed and written from multiple thread simultaneously. The `_balance` can be negative eventhough we check balance before doing withdraw.

#### Result

[image: Result1]

### Thread Safe version

To make withdraw method above thread safe, you need to wrap method body inside `lock` statement.

```
class Program
{
    private static decimal _balance = 100;
    private static readonly object _balanceLocker = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Withdraw, 23m);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Withdraw(object state)
    {
        lock (_balanceLocker)
        {
            var value = (decimal)state;
            var prevBalance = _balance;

            if (_balance >= value)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50); // simulate longer operation to emphasize data corruption
                _balance = _balance - value;
                Console.WriteLine("Balance {0}. Withdraw {1}. Balance after withdraw {2}", prevBalance, value, _balance);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Balance {0}. Withdraw {1}. Withdraw failed", prevBalance, value);
        }
    }
}
```

With code above, eventhough `_withdraw` is accessed from multiple threads, it will never be zero.

#### Result

[image]